# Azure Pipelines; In there an api call for Run Next?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know there's no way to add priority to jobs, but I can find the job I care about and click [Run Next] to bump to the top of the queue. Is there an api call to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an api call to do the same?

Yes. You can use the following API Call to achieve this feaure.

Rest API url:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{PoolID}/jobrequests/{AgentJobId}?lockToken=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&updateOptions=1&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Request Body:

```
{"requestId":AgentJobId}
```

You can get the Agent Job Id in **Organization Settings -> Agent Pool -> Jobs**

For example:

[image]

Then it will set the Run Next option for the Agent job.